# GridComputeExecutionRejectedException not handled when GridJobStealingCollisionSpi is used

Tags: gridgain

I've been successfully using GridGain for more than 3 years and besides a few bumps it worked very smoothly. At least I've always been able to figure out what was wrong (also due to very solid documentation and examples). Well, until now..

For one of my projects I was trying to enable job stealing in a computational grid powered by GridGain 6.5.0. The configuration went smoothly, however, from time to time I get GridComputeExecutionRejectedException, which bubbles all the way up to the client. A strange thing is that GridComputeExecutionRejectedException is supposed to be detected and routed by the Failover policy provided in the result method of standard GridComputeTaskAdapter (which I extend):

```
public GridComputeJobResultPolicy result(GridComputeJobResult res, List<GridComputeJobResult> rcvd) throws GridException {

    GridException e = res.getException();

    // Try to failover if result is failed.
    if (e != null) {
        // Don't failover user's code errors.
        if (e instanceof GridComputeExecutionRejectedException ||
            e instanceof GridTopologyException ||
            // Failover exception is always wrapped.
            e.hasCause(GridComputeJobFailoverException.class))
            return FAILOVER;

        throw new GridException("Remote job threw user exception (override or implement GridComputeTask.result(..) " +
        "method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception).", e);
    }

    // Wait for all job responses.
    return WAIT;
}
```

The exception thrown during a collision follows:

```
014-10-26 23:57:33,190 [http-bio-8080-exec-13] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - GridComputeExecutionRejectedException occurred when processing request: [POST] /evoRun/runEvolution
Job was cancelled before execution [jobSes=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1414392425356, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e2e1b6c, clsLdrId=4faab505941-ea582293-39ba-4648-9022-596e6626954b, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, sesId=7f4e9505941-b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3, startTime=1414392785621, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e2e1b6c, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3], jobId=55ee9505941-8522cc8b-10fb-4afd-945f-caa0e0c561f0], job=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionInputTask$1@380042f5]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation
. Stacktrace follows:
class org.gridgain.grid.compute.GridComputeExecutionRejectedException: Job was cancelled before execution [jobSes=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1414392425356, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e2e1b6c, clsLdrId=4faab505941-ea582293-39ba-4648-9022-596e6626954b, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, sesId=7f4e9505941-b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3, startTime=1414392785621, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2e2e1b6c, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=b2e9befc-051f-4e17-ba8d-bbafbe9cd7a3], jobId=55ee9505941-8522cc8b-10fb-4afd-945f-caa0e0c561f0], job=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionInputTask$1@380042f5]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.onBeforeActivateJob(GridJobProcessor.java:1190)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.access$1500(GridJobProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$CollisionJobContext.activate(GridJobProcessor.java:1469)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.collision.jobstealing.GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.checkBusy(GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.java:640)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.collision.jobstealing.GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.onCollision(GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.java:589)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.collision.GridCollisionManager.onCollision(GridCollisionManager.java:124)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.handleCollisions(GridJobProcessor.java:669)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1089)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1732)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've also found out that the piece of code responsible for activating jobs in GridJobStealingCollisionSpi has a comment "We also need to make sure that job is not being rejected by another thread." Could it be that exactly the scenario described in the comment somehow occurred? (I know there is a synchronized block in the code that should prevent that.)

Anyway, I'll highly appreciate any help!

My configuration file follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">

        <property name="marshaller">
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.marshaller.optimized.GridOptimizedMarshaller">
                <property name="requireSerializable" value="false"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVTS_TASK_EXECUTION"/>
        </property>

        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.sharedfs.GridTcpDiscoverySharedFsIpFinder"/>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

    <property name="loadBalancingSpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.loadbalancing.adaptive.GridAdaptiveLoadBalancingSpi">
            <property name="loadProbe">
                <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.loadbalancing.adaptive.GridAdaptiveProcessingTimeLoadProbe"/> 
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="collisionSpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.collision.jobstealing.GridJobStealingCollisionSpi">
            <property name="activeJobsThreshold" value="28"/>
            <property name="waitJobsThreshold" value="0"/>
                <property name="messageExpireTime" value="3000"/>
                <property name="maximumStealingAttempts" value="5"/>
                <property name="stealingEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>

    <property name="failoverSpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.failover.jobstealing.GridJobStealingFailoverSpi">
            <property name="maximumFailoverAttempts" value="5"/>
        </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="swapSpaceSpi">
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.swapspace.noop.GridNoopSwapSpaceSpi"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Edit**: As requested here is my abstract Task class:

```
public abstract class GridCollectionInputTask<IN,OUT,JOB_OUT> extends GridComputeTaskSplitAdapter<Collection<IN>, OUT> {

    /** Auto-injected grid logger. */
    @GridLoggerResource
    private GridLogger log = null;

    private final ArgumentCallable<IN,JOB_OUT> callable;

    public GridCollectionInputTask(ArgumentCallable<IN,JOB_OUT> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<? extends GridComputeJob> split(int gridSize, Collection<IN> inputs) throws GridException {
      List<GridComputeJob> jobs = new ArrayList<GridComputeJob>(inputs.size());

      for (IN input : inputs) {
          jobs.add(new GridComputeJobAdapter(input) {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public JOB_OUT execute() {
                return callable.call((IN) argument(0));
              }
          });
      }
      return jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public OUT reduce(List<GridComputeJobResult> results) throws GridException {
        Collection<JOB_OUT> jobResults = new ArrayList<JOB_OUT>();
        for (GridComputeJobResult res : results)
            jobResults.add((JOB_OUT) res.getData());
        return createTaskOutput(jobResults);
    }

    protected abstract OUT createTaskOutput(Collection<JOB_OUT> jobResults);
}
```

**Edit:** After introducing a try-catch block in the service class (that calls the grid) I got a full stack showing surprisingly also GridTopologyException:

```
2014-10-29 19:43:07,896 [http-bio-8080-exec-32] ERROR impl.EvolutionServiceImpl  - Evolution run failed!
edu.banda.coel.CoelRuntimeException: 'GridFitnessEvaluatorBOTaskAdapter' failed on grid.
    at edu.banda.coel.server.grid.ComputationalGrid.runOnGridSync(ComputationalGrid.java:231)
        ...
    at edu.banda.coel.server.service.impl.EvolutionServiceImpl.evolve(EvolutionServiceImpl.java:125)
    at com.banda.math.domain.evo.EvoRunController.runEvolution(EvoRunController.groovy:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.gridgain.grid.GridTopologyException: Failed to failover a job to another node (failover SPI returned null) [job=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionInputTask$1@47ba5075, node=GridTcpDiscoveryNode [id=368ffe13-76c7-42f6-9339-a34c772c0931, addrs=[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500, /xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=24, loc=false, ver=6.5.0#20140925-sha1:48190079]]
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.failover(GridTaskWorker.java:984)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:757)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:906)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1138)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:654)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1800(GridIoManager.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$6.body(GridIoManager.java:615)
    at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: class org.gridgain.grid.compute.GridComputeExecutionRejectedException: Job was cancelled before execution [jobSes=GridJobSessionImpl [ses=GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, dep=LocalDeployment [super=GridDeployment [ts=1414636288878, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@684be8b8, clsLdrId=3bab4ee5941-368ffe13-76c7-42f6-9339-a34c772c0931, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=java.lang.String, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=0]], taskClsName=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionTask, sesId=cc04ede5941-e05a00ce-2864-46a8-bf7c-4452f2a6d46e, startTime=1414636742023, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=e05a00ce-2864-46a8-bf7c-4452f2a6d46e, clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@684be8b8, closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=e05a00ce-2864-46a8-bf7c-4452f2a6d46e], jobId=21b4ede5941-368ffe13-76c7-42f6-9339-a34c772c0931], job=edu.banda.coel.server.grid.GridCollectionInputTask$1@1886b071]
For more information see:
    Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
    Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.onBeforeActivateJob(GridJobProcessor.java:1190)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.access$1500(GridJobProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$CollisionJobContext.activate(GridJobProcessor.java:1469)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.collision.jobstealing.GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.checkBusy(GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.java:640)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.collision.jobstealing.GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.onCollision(GridJobStealingCollisionSpi.java:589)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.managers.collision.GridCollisionManager.onCollision(GridCollisionManager.java:124)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.handleCollisions(GridJobProcessor.java:669)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.access$3000(GridJobProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobEventListener.onJobFinished(GridJobProcessor.java:1636)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.finishJob(GridJobWorker.java:807)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:533)
    at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:429)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Peter, can you please add code of your task implementation to the question?

Comment: Just added my core task class. I think it's pretty standard. As I've mentioned an unhanded GridComputeExecutionRejectedException appears only when using job stealing.

Comment: Could you set a breakpoint to java.lang.Throwable#printStackTrace(PrintStreamOrWriter) to detect where this exception is printed to the console?
Looks like this exception was not thrown, it was created and put to GridComputeJobResult, but somebody prints it to the console.

Comment: Since it's a production issue I could not really set a breakpoint, however, I was able to catch and log the full exception (see my edit). Also, I've realized I set activeJobsThreshold to 28, which is not equal to the total number of threads (default 100). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Please, look at the log before that stacktrace, is there any warnings or errors?

Comment: Sergey, yes, actually there is a warning! I've not seen it before because my logger filtered it out.
It seems like GridJobStealingFailoverSpi.failover returns null because the number of attempts exceeded the limit
    (WARNING: Job failover failed because number of maximum failover attempts is exceeded).
The problem is that GridTaskWorker handles this situation by issuing GridTopologyException that is thrown and gets undetected out of the grid.

Comment: A workaround is to simply increase maxFailoverAttempts to 10 or so, which should significantly reduce the error frequency... I'll try it now.

Comment: @Sergey, increasing maxFailoverAttempts helped but the exception still occurs. Should I create a Jira issue?

Comment: Jira issue already created: http://atlassian.gridgain.com/jira/browse/GG-9365

Comment: Great, thanks! Since I can't access GridGain's Jira pls. let me know when it's fixed in this thread.

Comment: @Peter, since the time this question was raised a lot of things happened. Presently GridGain's compute engine is a part of Apache Ignite and was reworked improved significantly. The issue you are reporting was moved to Apache Ignite JIRA
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2171
However, would you mind checking whether the issue still happens on your side?